# Why string comparison on command-line arguments doesn't work?

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << strcmp(argv[1], "id");
    return 0;
}
```

It returns false. What am I missing?

Thanks I got it working, Will accept answer in 4 minutes.

Comment: how are you calling the program from command line

Comment: You should always check whether a program obtained argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`strcmp` returns 0 if the c-strings being compared are equal. `0 == false`, therefore it's actually working.

Comment: if(argc == 2 && strcmp(argv[1], "id")) I'm using it like 
ai.exe id

But this block of code doesn't get executed.

Comment: `if(argc == 2 && !strcmp(argv[1], "id"))`

Comment: Did you actually read my answer? You're doing the exact opposite.

Comment: @AhmedJolani: Since `strcmp` returns a code and not a boolean, I would rather advise `strcmp(argv[1], "id") == 0`; in my opinion, it is more readable.

Comment: @LucTouraille it returns an integer and 0 is false, +-VE are true, so it's the same, but the later is superfluous.

Comment: @AhmedJolani Of course `0` is false, but in my opinion it is not very readable to treat integer values as booleans. For instance, I prefer reading `if (vec.size() > 0)` rather than `if (!vec.size())`. When I read `!strcmp(a,b)`, my mind translates that to `not a equals b`, which is not the correct interpretation. I need to look at the code twice to understand its meaning, which is not something I enjoy doing...

Comment: @LucTouraille by that you got a point, but there always `comments` anyway, and just saying we would do `str.substr(12,12)` like so `str.substr((size_t)12,(size_t)12)`.

Answer (score 2):

`strcmp` returns 0 if the 2 strings are [equal](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/).

**Tip: to avoid array out of bound exception (Segmentation Fault) use this:**

```
if (argv < 2) return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to start by just outputting argv[1]:

```
cout << argv[1] << endl;
```

Then you can see what value you're getting on argv[1] and take it from there. There's nothing wrong with your code, so I'm guessing that you've not configured your IDE properly to pass the correct argv[1] parameter.

As commented above, you *should* get a 0, not a false, though.

Comment: Well the thing is that I pass the "id" and compare it with "id" and argv[1] == "id" is false. With strcmp() it returns 0(which is good now) but one block of code doesn't get executed as stated in the comment of the first answer.

Comment: With C, "id" returns a `char *` pointing to the `i` of the string. `argv[1]` is another `char *`. So `argv[1]=="id"` compares two string pointers, not the strings they point to. Which is why it returns false.